# Zend framework based human resource software which is open source also

Tags: zend-framework, open-source

I am looking for a Zend framework based open source software/web application/cms.

It will be great help if anyone help me on this.

Thankx in advance.

Comment: have you tried any code yet ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can recommend 2 CMS platforms:

- Pimcore: Content/Product Management System and Rapid Development Platform based on ZF1,
- Bolt: Silex/Symfony based CMS

Comment: Thanks for this great help, actually I am trying to build a basic human resource management system, or we can say just a document management of the employees, by any chance......, is there any application on zend close to this idea..... once again thanx for your answer

Answer (score 0):

You can browse Sourceforge with the tag "Zend" like  [Here](http://sourceforge.net/directory/os%3awindows/freshness%3arecently-updated/?q=zend&sort=popular) you will find a lot of web application based on Zend Framework.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for this great help, actually I am trying to build a basic human resource management system, or we can say just a document management of the employees, by any chance......, is there any application on zend close to this idea..... once again thanx for your answer